# InvalidRequestContent response from topics api

Tags: azure, text-analysis, azure-cognitive-services

I want to use the topics API (https://westus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/text/analytics/v2.0/topics) but I get a BadRequest response for this input file:

```
{
  "documents": [
    {
      "id": "1",
      "text": "Hi. I think it's classic, relevant and yeah ... it's good I think"
    }
  ],
  "stopWords": [],
  "stopPhrases": []
}
```

I make the call using curl:

```
curl -X POST https://westus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/text/analytics/v2.0/topics -d @inputFile -H "Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key: <my_api_key>" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Accept: application/json"
```

The response is:

```
{"code":"BadRequest","message":"Invalid request","innerError":{"code":"InvalidRequestContent","message":"Requests to this API should contain at least 100 documents, where each document is not null or empty","minimumNumberOfDocuments":100}}
```

Note: the input JSON structure conforms with the requirements (https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/cognitive-services-text-analytics-quick-start/)

Can somebody tell what is wrong?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The error is clear, you need to add at least 100 documents like in the samples:

```
"documents": [
    {
        "id": "1",
        "text": "First document"
    },
    ...
    {
        "id": "100",
        "text": "Final document"
    }
]
```

Comment: Thank you, Peter, but I think the 100 documents are the upper limit of the documents not a requirement.

Comment: My mistake. Thank you, Peter. I confused the 100 documents with the 1000 max limit.